# How does gas fees incur for user

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

I've just started on blockchain. A question keep on. Arising in my mind -
For any application there will be on provider and one consumer. Taking example of Audius, artist can upload there songs. But since this is doing update operation on blockchain, artist will end up paying for this. Or in a chatting app, user will be paying to send message. In voting app user will pay for casting votes.

So is my understanding correct that if there is any updates on blockchain, it will be chargeable operation. And even if any service where provider has to pay, how does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of ​​a gas fee is necessary in the context of blockchain for several reasons. Perhaps the main one is Halting's problem. Currently, the ethereum network transaction fee is very expensive, but the idea is that this fee will decrease with the arrival of ethererem 2.0. In some other chains, like polygon, the gas rate is much cheaper. Another option is for the dApp itself to make the payment, instead of the user. Certainly what you said is an issue that needs to be resolved, but it is necessary to understand that even today, in web2.0, there is a cost, such as hosting the app at a server. It's impossible to take the cost out, it's just not clear yet the best way how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with what you mentioned Joao Paulo. There is cost associated with the server maintenance, hosting & other things in web 2.0. Is there any place where i can find case studies or business models of the dapps? It seems strange to me on how they are attracting user base where they have pay.